# PostgreSQL jsonb need a vacuum full after massive updates

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using postgreSQL 9.6 and updating multiple times a jsonb column using `jsonb_set()` function.

The problem I'm facing is that, after every update, the disk space used by the table grows exponentially even reaching 10GB for a single row.

After a full vacuum on the table the disk space drops down to some megabytes.

Is there any solution or better approach to this problem?

I already tried creating less json keys and insert everything in a json array value

```sql
UPDATE foo SET test_column = jsonb_set(test_column , '{"$key_name"}', '"$json_value"');
```

Update:

Thank you for your comments, I got some updates:

I've found that if the json contains a url as field value, the space grows exponentially. removing the link in the json fix partially the problem and the autovacuum works better (i've set it to run more frequently on the table). This is an example of the json:

```
{"15": [{"type": "Image", "order": "001", "assetId": "242753", "properties": {}, "publicLink": "http://www.yyy.com/232f3.jpg", "firstExport": false}], "20": [{"type": "Image", "order": "001", "assetId": "290818", "properties": {}, "publicLink": "http://www.yyy.com/8826d.jpg", "firstExport": false}]}
```

when this json reach 2000 keys the table space is around 160MB and the autovacuum doesn't clean anything. Manually running a autovacuum full drops the space to only 8000KB

The same json, with 2000 keys but without the urls inside takes only 30MB and the autovacuum seems to work properly.

Comment: It doesn't grow exponentially, but it will make a copy of the row when you update.  How big is this row?  Is autovacuum running on the table?

Comment: Yeah autovacuum is running on the table but dowsn't seem to clear the table correctly. Only the full vacuum does the job.
The json in the row can contain hundreds keys

Comment: A regular VACUUM will not usually shrink the space used, but it will free up space for future reuse, so that the next bulk update will not cause much further growth.  I think you are simply not giving it a chance to do its job.

Comment: adding some informations: the problem doesn't seem to be strinctly related to the multiple updates, even one update takes a lot more space than it does after a vacuum.
The problem is that the table space on disk grows too much and i can't wait for a vacuum to run cause the table can take over 10GB of space for lot of hours before the vacuum starts.
Is it a normal behave that a jsonb column takes 10GB and then drops down to 20MB after a vacuum?

Comment: This will not happen unless you have lots of updates in a very short time or you misconfigured autovacuum. Do you have a reproducible test case?

Comment: I edited my question with some updates based on your advices